Choosing a suitable title for this article about Hanfu
This article comes from a test. I know this kind of question is not welcomed here, but I have indeed made much efforts, including discussing with multiple teachers, but haven't been able to reach a consensus.

Hanfu fashion has become popular among young people. China has welcomed Western fashion and futuristic designs for many years, but a growing number of young people are now looking to the past for fashion advice.
If you look closely around your city, you might notice hanfu, the traditional clothing of the Han ethnic group. According to a report by an online shopping website, more than 2 million hanfu were sold in 2018. The number of hanfu buyers increased by 92 percent. The average age of buyers was 21, with about 52 percent between 19 and 24 years old.
But why has this traditional clothing become popular among young Chinese people?
For some of them, it's the clothes for relaxation. Dafan, a 24-year-old college student, told CGTN that dressing in hanfu is a way for her to run from the trouble of real life. Modern clothing, on the other hand, is the identity people need to show every day. “Hanfu and modern clothing help me to show the different sides in me,” she explained.
Other young peopte like hanfu because of the culture behind it. They think it is a way to reconnect with traditions. Its wide sleeves, crossed collars and flowing robes bring people back to ancient times. “What's behind hanfu is the inheritance of the Chinese civilisation,” Nanhe, a 21-year-old clothes store owner, told CGTN.
“Many Chinese people are having connection with hanfu, as it helps them build their national identity and belonging,” Zhang Yiwu, a professor of Chinese literature at Peking University, told China Daily.
Question: What can be the best title for the passage:
A. Hanfu — Chinese Traditional Clothing
B. Hanfu — Chinese Comfortable Clothing
C. Hanfu — Chinese Fashionable Clothing
D. Hanfu — Chinese Best-Known Clothing

The current outcome of my discussion with the teachers:

 There are two main viewpoints: A and C.

 Reasons for choosing C:
 - The article is about the current state of Hanfu, nothing to do with its traditionality
 - This article extensively discusses the status of Hanfu among the young, implying that it has become fashionable
 - Hanfu is very old, but now it has become popular again. The dash can indicate a turning point

 Reasons for choosing A:
 - The dash can indicate supplementary explanation
 - It conveys the meaning of 'new', while Hanfu is not new
 - Hanfu has always held a place among the elderly, but in recent years it has become popular among young people

 Another interesting point is that when focusing on the third paragraph, those who agree with A believe that this paragraph intends to emphasize its traditionality, while those who agree with C do the opposite.


A does not  convey the meaning 'new' - 'traditional' clothing is the style that has been worn for many generations. in the past. You could change C to 'back in fashion in China'.

The passage is about the popularity of hanfu in modern Chinese fashion, and "C" does the best job describing this.  The first two paragraphs unambiguously declare that hanfu is fashionable and that the whole article is about fashion.  The last two paragraphs give various reasons for the current popularity of hanfu.  "Hanfu" is defined as "traditional Han Chinese clothing," so "A" would be redundant and insufficient, unless the sole purpose of the passage was to define the meaning of "hanfu."  I think some people are hung up on "A" because of the way the answers are formatted, like a definition.  If you completely disregard the actual question, "A" answers the question "which of these is the best definition of the word 'hanfu'?"  This is hard to resist since questions like this are common in tests.  Also, "C" is not a very satisfying title, I wouldn't use it in real life for that passage.

Multiple-choice answers like this question aren't usually welcome on ELL. Suggestion D is imho beyond salvation, but idiomatically, all the others would be much more natural with Chinese as the second adjective, not the first. Apart from that, it's a stylistic choice, where it's meaningless to suggest that any one is better than the others. But here's my suggested title that's not in the list...

Hanfu is the New Chinese Black


be the new something (idiom)  Cambridge Dictionary
used to say that something is now more popular or fashionable than the thing that it replaces
This season fashion designers have declared that brown is the new black

This particular definition doesn't include the word black, and the example itself happens to have another colour (brown) as the subject. But it's not uncommon to see X is the new black with a wide range of values for X - anything just coming [back] into fashion, not just colours.
